# UsbConnection.bulkTransfer returns "-1". What does it mean?

Tags: android, usb

According to the doc negative response means failure.
How to know what's wrong? is there any full doc about error types?

For more curious:
I'm trying to upload arduino sketch via USB. First i'm getting bootloader attention by turning DTR/RTS off/on and then sending data using Stk500 protocol. It's working fine if running on mac/arduino via usb (rxtx serial is used) so i think it should work on android AS-IS (just change serial), but it fails to send the data after DTR/RTS toggling.

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I feel like http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [bulkTransfer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#bulkTransfer%28android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> Returns
>
> length of data transferred (or zero) for success, or negative value for failure

So if you're getting `-1`, then it means your data transfer has failed. You could look into the logcat, or work with breakpoints to figure out why.

Comment: nothing in the log cat, no breakpoints can be set as it's android os class

Comment: Minus one (-1) is also returned if the timeout is reached

Answer (score 1):

Well, after diving into log i was able to handle it - don't close/open usb few times in a row

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to claim the interface:

```
deviceConnection.ClaimInterface(interf, true);
```